# Best way to handle Resultsets and other data fteched from HTML in a servlet

Tags: java, html, postgresql, servlets

Ok so for our Uni project we are making a website to store information about churches (I know super interesting right -.-).

Basicly it just needs to have church information in a database and when a user clicks or searchs for a church it needs to pull the church information along with user comments from the database.

So far I have a HTML form that delivers a comment to the servlet/database and outputs it using a resultset. I was just wondering what the best method would be for handling multiple information as now that I'm trying to deliver both comments and the church information I'm kinda lost as to how to store it.

Thanks in advance!

Ow and here is my code for reference:

HTML

```
    <form method="get" action="dbtest" id="form1">
        <fieldset>
        <p>Please enter you're Name:</p>
        <input type="text" name="author" size="10" id="name"/><br />
        <p>Please enter you're Email here:</p>
        <input type="text" name="author_email" size="10" id="email"/><br />
        <p>Please enter you're comment here:</p>
        <input type="text" name="comment_text" size="10" id="comment"/><br />
        <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit_button" />
        </p>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Servlet

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author mxk12ycu
 */
public class dbtest extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP
     * <code>GET</code> and
     * <code>POST</code> methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String authorName = request.getParameter("author");
        String authorEmail = request.getParameter("author_email");
        String commentText = request.getParameter("comment_text");


        try {
            //Holding SQL statement
            String SQL;
            String insertSQL;

            //insertSQL = "INSERT INTO comments VALUES('0002')" + authorName + authorEmail + commentText + ("('29 Nov 2012','002')");
            //insertSQL = "INSERT INTO comments VALUES (default,'Ryan H','Test@hotmail.com','TestComments','29 Nov 2012','1')";

           //insertSQL = "INSERT INTO comments (author, author_email, comment_text, comment_date, church_id) VALUES ('" + authorName + "'," + "'" + authorEmail + "'," + "'" + commentText + "', '29 Nov 2012', '1')";
           //insertSQL = "INSERT INTO comments VALUES ('Ryan Holder', 'test@hotmail.com', 'Comment here', '30 Nov 2012', 'default', '1')";
            insertSQL = "INSERT INTO comments VALUES (default, " + "'" + authorName + "'," + "'" + authorEmail + "'," + "'" + commentText + "', '29 Nov 2012', '1')";
            SQL = "SELECT * FROM churches, comments";

            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:postgresql:ChurchSearch",
                    "postgres",
                    "*****");

            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

            statement.executeUpdate(insertSQL);

            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(SQL);


             /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Test Comment Servlet</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet test at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("<h2>Comment Form</h2>");

            while (resultSet.next()) {
            out.println("<p>");
            out.println(resultSet.getString("author"));
            out.println("</p>");
            out.println("<p>");
            out.println(resultSet.getString("author_email"));
            out.println("</p>");
            out.println("<p>");
            out.println(resultSet.getString("comment_text"));
            out.println("</p>");
            }
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");

            connection.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e);
        }
        finally {            
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to use the [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). On the other hand, you must be sure to close the connection to the database.

```
Connection conn = null;
try {
    conn = // get connection;

    // do database operations

} catch (final SQLException e) {
    throw new DAOException(e);
} finally {
    if (conn != null) {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (final SQLException ex) {
            LOG.warning("message warning to log");
        }
    }
}
```

This releases all resources used by the connection.

About MVC, you can find more information in [Integrating Servlets and JSP: The Model View Controller (MVC) Architecture](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/pdf/struts/MVC.pdf). You can also use a framework like Struts, Spring MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Create A DAO(database access objects) class ..Handle connections.

```
 public class DAO {

static private Connection conn = null;
static private String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/<databse name>";
static private String USERNAME = "root";
static private String PASSWORD = "root";
static private String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";


private static Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException,
        SQLException {

    if (conn == null) {
        Class.forName(DRIVER);
        System.out.println("Driver Initailizing");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    }
    return conn;
}

public static ResultSet selectQuery(String query) throws SQLException,
        ClassNotFoundException {

    //Read the query from the servlet class only SQL query
    System.out.println(query);
    ResultSet rs = DAO.getConnection().createStatement().executeQuery(query);
            //return the result set back to servlet class
    return rs;
}
```

Thanks,

Pavan